# Error when trying to create a partial class

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, partial

I have created a Area class using Linq-to-SQL.

Now I want to create a partial class of the same name so I can implement validation.

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Data.Linq.Table<SeguimientoDocente.Area>`'
>   to
>   '`System.Linq.IQueryable<SeguimientoDocente.Models.Area>`'    C:\Users\Sergio\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\SeguimientoDocente\SeguimientoDocente\Models\AreaRepository.cs  14  20  SeguimientoDocente

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SeguimientoDocente.Models
{
    public class AreaRepository
    {
        private SeguimientoDataContext db = new SeguimientoDataContext();

        public IQueryable<Area> FindAllAreas()
        {
            return db.Areas;
        }

        public Area GetArea(int id)
        {
            return db.Areas.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);
        }

        public void Add(Area area)
        {
            db.Areas.InsertOnSubmit(area);
        }

        public void Delete(Area area)
        {
            db.Areas.DeleteOnSubmit(area);
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SeguimientoDocente.Models
{
    public partial class Area
    {

    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly because your partial class is not in the right namespace. Go into the .designer.cs file of the LINQ model, look for the generated Area class, and make sure the namespace you wrapped your partial class in matches.

**EDIT**

I just fixed the formatting in your question. The error message does in fact indicate that your partial class is in the wrong namespace.

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Data.Linq.Table<SeguimientoDocente.Area>`'
>   to
>   '`System.Linq.IQueryable<SeguimientoDocente.Models.Area>`'

As you can see from the error above, you need to change the namespace your partial class is in to be SeguimientoDocente, not SeguimientoDocente.Models. As it stands now, they are two completely different incompatible types that happen to have the same simple name.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you that the problem is in line 14 of the `AreaRepository.cs` file. Specifically, you are trying to return `db.Areas` from a method whose return type is `IQueryable<Area>`, though `db.Areas` is in fact of type `System.Data.Linq.Table`.

Comment: I'm following this tutorial. Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that this error only appears when I add the partial Area class. When there is no Area partial, the code compiles and words correctly.

Comment: Actually the OP's question was not properly marked up. Normally Table<T> does indeed implement IQueryable<T> but in this case he's inadvertently defined a T2 that has the same simple name as T1.

Comment: @Josh Thank you. I considered that, but didn't see a namespace import in the class that uses the DataContext. I see now why that is, though.